# SQLITE view, how to calculate diff between buy and sell into same row

Tags: sqlite, compare, difference

I am quit new at this (sqlite) using sqlite studio.
I have a table with many rows, trying to view  dates, objects, purchase price, sold price and the difference.

This is what I get

```
DATE    OBJ     BOUGHT  SOLD    DIFF
2009    OBJ1    235000  NULL    NULL
2012    OBJ2    255500  NULL    NULL
2021    OBJ3    305400  NULL    NULL
2012    OBJ1    NULL    255500  NULL
2021    OBJ2    NULL    309000  NULL
```

---

This is what I want

```
DATE    OBJ     BOUGHT  SOLD    DIFF
2009    OBJ1    235000  255500  20500
2012    OBJ2    255500  309000  53500
2021    OBJ3    305400  NULL    NULL
```

---

Code:

```
SELECT strftime('%Y', Op_Date) Year, Op_Obj OBJ ifnull(Op_TTBuy, 0) BOUGHT, ifnull(Op_TTSell, 0) SOLD, (Op_TTSell - Op_TTBuy) DIFF
FROM Operations
```

I tried many ways..
Any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to group by year, something along these lines:

```
SELECT strftime('%Y', Op_Date) Year, max(Op_Ob) OBJ
, sum(ifnull(Op_TTBuy, 0)) BOUGHT
, sum(ifnull(Op_TTSell, 0)) SOLD
, (sum(Op_TTSell) - sum(Op_TTBuy)) DIFF
FROM Operations 
group by strftime('%Y', Op_Date)
order by strftime('%Y', Op_Date)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.. I tried that, the column SOLD is empty.. DId try all the possible GROUP BY and ORDER BY ..

Comment: please provide a sample of the Operations table, it might be a data related issue

Comment: I added the 'sum' as per your code, group by order GROUP BY Op_Obj and ORDER BY strftime('%Y', Op_Date), that DID the trick. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Glad to hear is sorted, I've updated the answer